# PHP IF Else Statement Not working

Tags: php

I'm having problems with my IF statement. Why does my code just always say that **a is NOT greater than b** what have I done wrong? Even when the number is greater it just says it's not?

```
<?php
//vars
$A = '454';
$B = '1001';
?>


<?php
function difference($val3, $val4)
{
    $subtract = ($val3 - $val4);
    return $subtract;
}

// random number generator function
function random($min, $max) 
{
  return rand($min,$max);
}


$ANum = random(1,$A);
$BNum = random(1,$B);
$difference = "-170"; //difference($teamANum, $teamBNum);


function result()
{
    if ($ANum > $BNum) 
        {
            echo "a is greater than b";
        } 
    else 
        {
             echo "a is NOT greater than b";
        }

}

?>

<?php
echo "A: ".$teamANum."\n";
echo "B: ".$teamBNum."\n";
echo "Difference: ".$difference."\n";
echo result()."\n";
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: What you are actually accomplishing here? You are using min, max, difference, randoms?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump`ing both `$ANum` and `$BNum` inside the your `result` function?

Comment: looks like a scope issue

Comment: LOL Why create a function called `random` that calls `rand`? Do you just like typing?

Comment: Thats just stuff from another code, I'm just concentrating on the IF statement - maybe something else in the script is wrong?

Comment: @AlienWebguy He is generating random out of random :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are out of scope.

```
function result($ANum, $BNum)
{

    if ($ANum > $BNum) 
        {
            echo "a is greater than b";
        } 
    else 
        {
             echo "a is NOT greater than b";
        }

}
```

Pass the variables as parameters to the function.

Comment: Ahhhhh globals ia bad :p try to ignore them

Comment: or better don't use globals and pass the variables as parameters to the `result()` function.

Comment: @Mr.Alien yeah, but that is the problem. But will edit anyway

Comment: Gaming the system :) Post a quick and fast answer, improve it during few minutes *in the shadow*

Comment: @j0k http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9745

Comment: @j0k what should I have done differently?

Comment: @InGodITrust Nope. And you seems to be prepared to this kind of answer since you find this short link in a really fast way!

Comment: @j0k ha ha. yeah, you gotta learn somewhere how to get points here. Have a nice night!

Answer (score 2):

Your function `result` doesn't know variables `$ANum` or `$BNum`.

```
function result($ANum, $BNum)
{
  if ($ANum > $BNum) 
  {
    echo "a is greater than b";
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo "a is NOT greater than b";
  }
}
```

By the way, last variables `$teamANum` & `$teamBNum` doesn't exists.

Comment: Wait for someone to post a quick and fast answer, and while he improves it during few minutes in the shadow, pop in your full version answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$ANum  $BNum` are not defined in `result()` hence they are both always 0.
This question suggest your next step is to actually work with a tutorial and concentrate on scope and functions.